# Operation synchronization different from class synchronization

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization

I have a WebService (.svc) class with

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

and I want to make some of it operations multiple not single and some single.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mark class as ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, make private synchronization field, and lock on that field on method entrancies which need to be Single.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class SomeSvc : ContractInterface
{
    private readonly Object _syncLock = new Object();

    // this method is ConcurrencyMode.Single
    public String SingleMethod1()
    {
         lock (_syncLock)
         {
             // method code here
         }
    }

    // this method is ConcurrencyMode.Single
    public String SingleMethod2()
    {
         lock (_syncLock)
         {
             // method code here
         }
    }

    // this method is ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
    public String MultipleMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use two different concurrency configurations in single service. As you can see the attribute is called `ServiceBehavior` = it affects whole service. If you want two different behaviors you must divide your code into two services. Also there is no `InstanceContextMode` specified in your attribute so there is possiblity that setting `ConcurrencyMode` to `Multiple` will have no effect.